# $\lim \frac{5^{\sin{h}}-1}{\tan{h}}$ as h goes to $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

> Find $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{5^{\sin{h}}-1}{\tan{h}}. $

How do you calculate the above limit?

My attempt:

$ \ell :=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{5^{\sin{h}}-1}{\tan{h}} $ .

Let $\quad t = \tan{h},\quad$ then: $\quad \sin(h) = \sin(\arctan{t}) = \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}.\quad$ Therefore:

$$\begin{aligned} \displaystyle \ell & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{5^{\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}}-1}{t} \\& =\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{5^{\dfrac{t+x}{\sqrt{(t+x)^2+1}}}-5^{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}}{t}\bigg|_{x=0} \\& = \frac{d}{dx} 5^{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}\bigg|_{x=0} \\& = \frac{5^{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}\log(5)}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)^3}}\bigg|_{x=0} \\& = \log(5). \end{aligned}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Perhaps a cleaner way to compute the limit would be to use [L'Hopital's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html)?

Comment: how ever $\ln(5)$ is the right result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right! But:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{5^{\sin(h)}-1}{\tan(h)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\cos(h)\left(5^{\sin(h)}-1\right)}{\sin(h)}=$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\cos(h)\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{5^{\sin(h)}-1}{\sin(h)}=$$
$$\cos(0)\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{5^{\sin(h)}-1}{\sin(h)}=$$
$$1\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{5^{\sin(h)}-1}{\sin(h)}=$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{5^{\sin(h)}-1}{\sin(h)}=$$

---

Let $u=\sin(h)$:

---

$$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{5^{u}-1}{u}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{5^u\ln(5)}{1}=\ln(5)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{5^{\sin x}-1}{\tan x}\to \frac{5^{\sin x}\cos x\ln 5}{\sec^2 x}=\left(\ln 5\right)5^{\sin x}\cos^3 x
$$
where I used L'Hopital's rule we can take limits
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{5^{\sin x}-1}{\tan x} =\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\ln 5\right)5^{\sin x}\cos^3 x = 5^0\cdot 1^3 \ln 5 = \ln 5
$$

Answer (score 1):

Because $(\tan h) / h \to 1,$ we can replace $\tan h$ with $h.$ We then are looking at

$$\frac{\exp (\sin h \ln 5) - 1}{h}.$$

Let $f(h) = \exp (\sin h \ln 5).$ Then the above equals

$$\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h-0}.$$

By definition of the derivative, this $\to f'(0),$ which is easily found to be $\exp (\sin h \ln 5)\cdot \cos h \ln 5\,|_{h=0} = 1\cdot 1 \cdot \ln 5 = \ln 5.$

(Note that we are not using L'Hopital here.)